# How map date with different API Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

How can I use date with different API (e.g., YouTube, Vimeo)? In state I have a table with objects, objects are different. I map this table to Component.

```
{items.map((item) => (<Item key={uuidv4()} product={item}></Item>))}
```

I don't have an idea how can I use here props to have `title`, `img` and `likeCount` when path to the goal is different.

Path to YouTube title:

```
const title = props.item.snippet.localized.title;
```

Path to Vimeo title:

```
const title = props.item.name;
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
export default function Video(props) {
    const title = props.item.snippet.localized.title || props.item.name;
    return (
        <div>{title}</div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to use this:

```js
{items.map((item) => (<Item key={uuidv4()} product={item.name ?? item.snippet.localized.title}></Item>))}
```

Otherwise a more complex arrow function is fine too:

```js
{items.map((item) => {
    const title = ...;
    return <Item key={uuidv4()} product={title/>;
})}
```

If your problem is that `props.item.snippet.localized.title` errors due to e.g. `.snippet` being `undefined`, try [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
const title = props.item.snippet?.localized?.title ?? props.item.name;
```

Comment: Thanks you bro, optional chaining solved my problem. Have a nice day !